Storing JWT in postgres through apache web server
My use case:- When I try to access to the proctected the resource, i want the requests to be forwarded to apache web server where apache web server should fetch the JWT token from auth0 and store that JWT token within the postgres.
NOTE I dont want to use any backend service to store jwt in postgres this should be handle through apache web server. Is it possible?
I have used mod_auth_openidc for token retireval from auth0 and this works properly but in next step before forwarding request i want to store the JWT token that i recieved from auth should be stored in postgres without calling any other service.
for token storing I used auth_dbd but didnt worked. Sharing the sample that i have created.
Any help is appriciated, let me know if anything else is required.
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost

    # Load the necessary modules
    LoadModule authn_dbd_module modules/mod_authn_dbd.so
    LoadModule dbd_module modules/mod_dbd.so
    LoadModule auth_openidc_module modules/mod_auth_openidc.so

    # OIDC configuration
    OIDCProviderMetadataURL https://*****************.auth0.com/.well-known/openid-configuration
    OIDCClientID ******************************
    OIDCClientSecret your_client_secret_here
    OIDCRedirectURI http://localhost/auth-callback
    OIDCCryptoPassphrase your_crypto_passphrase
    OIDCScope "openid profile email"
    OIDCSessionType server-cache

    LogLevel debug

    # Configure how tokens are stored 
    # OIDCSessionInDBOn
    # OIDCSessionType dbd

    # Session DBD Configuration
    DBDriver pgsql
    DBDParams "dbname=****** user=**** password=***** host=*****"
    DBDPersist on

    # Session handling
    Session On
    SessionDBDPerUser On
    SessionDBDCookieName session path=/
    SessionDBDInsertLabel "INSERT INTO oauth_sessions (session_id, session_data, expires_at) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"
    SessionDBDUpdateLabel "UPDATE oauth_sessions SET session_data = %s, expires_at = %s WHERE session_id = %s"

    # Protect the Spring Boot application endpoint
    <Location /hello>
        AuthType openid-connect
        Require valid-user
        Session On
    </Location>

    # Define the ScriptAlias at the virtual host level
    ScriptAlias /store-token /var/www/scripts/store_token.sh

    # OIDC Callback Location
    <Location /auth-callback>
        AuthType openid-connect
        Require valid-user

        # Pass the tokens as environment variables
        SetEnv OIDC_access_token %{OIDC_access_token}
        SetEnv OIDC_refresh_token %{OIDC_refresh_token}
        SetEnv OIDC_id_token %{OIDC_id_token}

        # Call the Bash script to handle the token storage
        SetHandler cgi-script
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteRule ^/auth-callback /store-token [L]
    </Location>

</VirtualHost>


#!/bin/bash

# Fetch the tokens from environment variables
ACCESS_TOKEN="${OIDC_access_token}"
REFRESH_TOKEN="${OIDC_refresh_token}"
ID_TOKEN="${OIDC_id_token}"

# Define PostgreSQL connection parameters
PGUSER="myuser"
PGPASSWORD="myuser"
PGHOST="localhost"
PGPORT="5432"
PGDATABASE="mydb"

# Insert tokens into the PostgreSQL database
psql -U "$PGUSER" -h "$PGHOST" -p "$PGPORT" -d "$PGDATABASE" -c \
"INSERT INTO oauth_tokens (access_token, refresh_token, id_token) VALUES ('$ACCESS_TOKEN', '$REFRESH_TOKEN', '$ID_TOKEN');"

# Optionally, output a response to the client
echo "Content-type: text/plain"
echo ""
echo "Tokens have been stored successfully in PostgreSQL."



